# JSTL fmt library throws 500 error, requires sessions enabled?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jstl

I'm developing a simple servlet/JSP, data-driven web site on Google App Engine. I've started to use the JSTL fmt library on some of my data entry forms and get the following session-related error when using tags `<fmt:dateFormat> and <fmt:numberFormat>:`

[java] java.lang.RuntimeException: Session support is not enabled in appengine-web.xml.  To enable sessions, put true in that file.  Without it, getSession() is allowed, but manipulation of sessionattributes is not.

The code in my JSP is, for example:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${dayList}" >
 <option><fmt:formatNumber value="${item}" pattern="00"/></option>
</c:forEach>
```

or

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" scope="page" class="java.util.Date" />
Now: ${now}<br/>
Year: <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="yyyy" />
```

When I comment these lines out, the page renders, when turned back on, the error results.

I don't have sessions enabled because I don't need them for this web application and read that it is better not to if you don't have to. I have confirmed that no attributes are session-scoped, the only occurrence of "session" in my NetBeans project is in web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Once I enable sessions on the appengine-web.xml everything works.

My research has pointed to some locale-related context parameters that you may set in the web.xml, namely:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>
    <param-value>en-US</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale</param-name>
    <param-value>en-US</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.timeZone</param-name>
    <param-value>EDT</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have redeployed with these parameters set (and with sessions off) and get the same error.

The JSTL fmt library seems that it would be very conveniet to use for dates and numbers and such on web forms, though at the end of the day it may be that I just need to enable sessions and move on -- but am I missing something here with regard to locale settings that causes the session to be referenced by default?  Is this something particular to App Engine perhaps?

Thanks

P.S.
This is the stack trace I get when sessions are disabled:

```
 [java] Aug 17, 2010 2:41:26 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
 [java] WARNING: /manage/events/new
 [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: Session support is not enabled in appengine-web.xml.  To enable sessions, put <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled> in that file.  Without it, getSession() is allowed, but manipulation of sessionattributes is not.
 [java]         at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.StubSessionManager$StubSession.throwException(StubSessionManager.java:67)
 [java]         at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.StubSessionManager$StubSession.setAttribute(StubSessionManager.java:63)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doSetAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:340)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.access$300(PageContextImpl.java:64)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl$4.run(PageContextImpl.java:314)
 [java]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.setAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:312)
 [java]         at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.SetLocaleSupport.setResponseLocale(SetLocaleSupport.java:209)
 [java]         at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.SetLocaleSupport.doEndTag(SetLocaleSupport.java:108)
 [java]         at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.update_005fevent_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_setLocale_0(update_005fevent_jsp.java:362)
 [java]         at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.update_005fevent_jsp._jspService(update_005fevent_jsp.java:117)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
 [java]         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
 [java]         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
 [java]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
 [java]         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 [java]         at com.cj.trim.trimFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at com.queerartfilm.web.JSTLConfigFilter.doFilter(JSTLConfigFilter.java:114)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 [java]         at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: can you provide a more complete stacktrace? i'm interested to see exactly where gae thinks it needs a session. it may be possible to avoid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very unfortunate. It look like you can't go around this. Your best bet is then to create custom EL functions which does the same. Here's an example how you could replace `fmt:formatDate`.

First create an EL functions class (just a simple static class):

```
package com.example;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public final class Functions {

    private Functions() {
        //
    }

    public static String formatDate(Date date, String pattern) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);
    }

}
```

Then create a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` (note: JSP 2.1 targeted, not sure what your GAE supports, it's maybe Servlet 2.4, if so then you need to redeclare it as JSP 2.0 taglib):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <display-name>Custom Functions</display-name>    
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>formatDate</name>
        <function-class>com.example.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String formatDate(java.util.Date, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Then you can use it as follows in your JSP:

```xml
<%@taglib uri="http://example.com/functions" prefix="f" %>
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
...
<p>Current year: ${f:formatDate(date, 'yyyy')}</p>
```

Comment: Hey there BalusC, thanks for your feedback and suggestion. I think this would be good, longer-term solution, but I would like to try and use the JSTL fmt library instead of having to re-implement the functionality myself. 



By the way, I find your weblog very informative and have learned a lot from reading your informative articles, tutorials, and your other response here on stackoverflow. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

I have recently run into the same problem, where JSTL code insists on setting a session-scope attribute to keep track of character encoding.  Because I want my application to scale to large numbers of concurrent users, I am avoiding servlet session creation entirely.

The first thing I did was to install a listener to log session creation/destruction and session attribute add/remove.  After running through all pages on my site, I had verified that session access was limited to the JSTL `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.request.charset` attribute.

Knowing that I only needed to handle a very specific case, I wrote a filter that wraps the HttpServletRequest and overrides the getSession() methods to return my own implementation of the HttpSession interface.  The session implementation is an instance variable of the filter, and uses init-params from the filter configuration to "support" a fixed set of name/value pairs that will be allowed as pseudo session-scope attributes.  Any attempt to set a session attribute, other than one configured in the filter, will result in an exception.

I hope this is helpful to anyone faced with the competing goals of suppressing session creating and using JSTL tags.

- Jack

Here is the StatelessRequestFilter class:

```
package com.your.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class StatelessRequestFilter implements Filter
{
    private FilterConfig config;

    public void init( FilterConfig config )
        throws ServletException
    {
        if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
        {
            logger().debug( "init() called" );
        }

        this.config = config;

        if( logger().isInfoEnabled() )
        {
            // Look for any configuration name/value pairs.  These will be considered valid
            // pseudo session attributes.  If a set operation tries to set one of these 
            // properties, it will be ignored -- as opposed to throwing an exception
            Enumeration<String> initParamNames = config.getInitParameterNames();
            while( initParamNames.hasMoreElements() )
            {
                logger().info( "init(): attributes defined in the filter configuration..." );
                String paramName = initParamNames.nextElement();
                String paramValue = config.getInitParameter( paramName );
                logger().info( "init(): " + paramName + " = " + paramValue );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see javax.servlet.Filter#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain)
     * 
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @param chain
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws ServletException
     */
    public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain )
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        if( logger().isInfoEnabled() )
        {
            logger().info( "doFilter(): wrapping request with StatelessHttpRequestWrapper" );
        }
        ServletRequest weDontNeedNoStinkinSessionsRequest = new StatelessHttpRequestWrapper(
            (HttpServletRequest) request );
        chain.doFilter( weDontNeedNoStinkinSessionsRequest, response );
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
        {
            logger().debug( "destroy() called" );
        }
    }

    public class StatelessHttpRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
    {

        public StatelessHttpRequestWrapper( HttpServletRequest request )
        {
            super( request );
        }

        /**
         * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper#getSession()
         * 
         * @return
         */

        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession()
        {
            return statelessSession;
        }

        /**
         * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper#getSession(boolean)
         * 
         * @param create
         * @return
         */

        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession( boolean create )
        {
            if( create == true )
            {
                logger()
                    .warn(
                        "getSession( boolean ):  Calling this method with 'true' will NOT create a new HttpSession!" );
            }
            return statelessSession;
        }

    }

    // This object will be used by all threads going through this filter
    private final PseudoHttpSession statelessSession = new PseudoHttpSession();

    public class PseudoHttpSession implements HttpSession
    {

        public Object getAttribute( String arg0 )
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getAttribute(): '" + arg0 + "'" );
            }
            return config.getInitParameter( arg0 );
        }

        public Enumeration<String> getAttributeNames()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getAttributeNames()" );
            }
            return config.getInitParameterNames();
        }

        public long getCreationTime()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getCreationTime()" );
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public String getId()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getId()" );
            }
            return null;
        }

        public long getLastAccessedTime()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getLastAccessedTime()" );
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public int getMaxInactiveInterval()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getMaxInactiveInterval()" );
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public ServletContext getServletContext()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getServletContext()" );
            }
            return null;
        }

        public HttpSessionContext getSessionContext()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getSessionContext()" );
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Object getValue( String arg0 )
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getValue(): '" + arg0 + "'" );
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String[] getValueNames()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "getValueNames()" );
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void invalidate()
        {
            logger().warn( "invalidate(): ignoring request to invalidate session!" );
        }

        public boolean isNew()
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "isNew()" );
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void putValue( String arg0, Object arg1 )
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "putValue(): '" + arg0 + "'" + ": " + arg1 );
            }
            String configAttribute = config.getInitParameter( arg0 );
            if( configAttribute == null )
            {
                logger().error( "putValue(): unconfigured attribute: " + arg0 );
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "PseudoHttpSession cannot be used to store state, hence the 'pseudo' part of the name" );
            }
        }

        public void setAttribute( String arg0, Object arg1 )
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "setAttribute(): '" + arg0 + "'" + ": " + arg1 );
            }
            String configAttribute = config.getInitParameter( arg0 );
            if( configAttribute == null )
            {
                logger().error( "setAttribute(): unconfigured attribute: " + arg0 );
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "PseudoHttpSession cannot be used to store state, hence the 'pseudo' part of the name" );
            }
        }

        public void removeAttribute( String arg0 )
        {
            logger().warn( "removeAttribute(): '" + arg0 + "' ignored!" );
        }

        public void removeValue( String arg0 )
        {
            logger().warn( "removeValue(): '" + arg0 + "' ignored!" );
        }

        public void setMaxInactiveInterval( int arg0 )
        {
            if( logger().isDebugEnabled() )
            {
                logger().debug( "setMaxInactiveInterval(): '" + arg0 + "'" );
            }
            logger().warn( "setMaxInactiveInterval(): call ignored!" );
        }

    }

    private Logger logger()
    {
        return Logger.getLogger( this.getClass() );
    }

}
```

And here is how it is configured within web.xml:

```
<!-- The 'WeDontNeedNoStinkinSessions' filter will wrap the incoming HTTP request to
         override the getSession() methods to return a 'PseudoHttpSession'.  This object 
         prevents creation of servlet sessions. The request is only wrapped if the 
         HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() method returns 'null'. -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>WeDontNeedNoStinkinSessionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sherwin.sd.web.filter.StatelessRequestFilter</filter-class>
    <!--
        PseudoHttpSession with treat any 'init-param' name/value pairs as legal session-scope
        attributes.  If a session attempts to set an attribute whose name matches an init-param
        below, the setAttribute() call is ignored, as opposed to raising an exception.  When
        getAttribute() is called, the param-value is returned.

        For example, when in contribution mode, something attempts to save a character 
        encoding to the session.  Since this value is always the same (and to the best 
        of our knowledge never used!), it is reasonable to treat this as a static, configurable
        property.
    -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.request.charset</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<!-- The 'WeDontNeedNoStinkinSessions' is applied to all FORWARDs. -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WeDontNeedNoStinkinSessionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/whatever/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using this page directive:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

While waiting to see what the full stacktrace reveals, here's another option. This [filter](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Filters) will look for JSTL config params in web.xml and set them as request attributes in the hope that this will short-circuit any need for GAE to access the session:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config;

public class JSTLConfigFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String[] JSTL_CONFIG_PARAMS = { Config.FMT_FALLBACK_LOCALE,
                                                         Config.FMT_LOCALE,
                                                         Config.FMT_LOCALIZATION_CONTEXT,
                                                         Config.FMT_TIME_ZONE,
                                                         Config.SQL_DATA_SOURCE,
                                                         Config.SQL_MAX_ROWS };
    private final Map<String, String> jstlConfig = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        ServletContext ctx = config.getServletContext();
        for (String param : JSTL_CONFIG_PARAMS) {
            String value = ctx.getInitParameter(param);
            if (value != null) {
                this.jstlConfig.put(param, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        this.jstlConfig.clear();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : this.jstlConfig.entrySet()) {
            Config.set(request, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Variations are, of course, possible, but hopefully you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I implemented the Filter as you describe above, however disabling sessions still causes and error. I appended the stack trace to my question above.

Comment: the stacktrace indicates that the issue is with `<fmt:setLocale>`. how are you using it in your page? i believe one of the side-effects of `<fmt:setLocale>` is to try and store the response's char encoding in a session attribute. however, it should only do this if `PageContext.getSession()` is not null...

Answer (score 1):

Code wich cause the issue is in fmt lib SetLocaleSupport class is

```
    static void setResponseLocale(PageContext pc, Locale locale) {
    .../...
// get response character encoding and store it in session attribute
if (pc.getSession() != null) {
        try {
        pc.setAttribute(RequestEncodingSupport.REQUEST_CHAR_SET,
            response.getCharacterEncoding(),
            PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {} // invalidated session ignored
}
}
```

it blindlessly put the charset in session. You can't do much...