# JSTL format tag

Tags: jsp, jstl

Trying to populate and formate a date value inside an INPUT text field. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<spring:bind path="salesData.weekEndDate">
 <input type="text" name="${status.expression}"
 value="${fmt:formateDate pattern='MM/mm/YYYY' status.value}"
/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [JSTL `fmt` taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) exists of `<fmt:xxx>` tags, not `${fmt:xxx}` functions.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<input type="text" name="${status.expression}"
    value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${status.value}" />" />
/>
```

*(note that days are to be represented as `dd`, not `mm` and that years are to be represented as `yyyy`, not `YYYY`, see also [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all valid patterns)*

If your IDE jerks about the nested tags (which should run perfectly fine however) or you get itch from it, make use of the `var` attribute so that your HTML/XML ends up well formed.

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${status.value}" var="statusDate" />
<input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${statusDate}" />
```

If you really like to have a `${fmt:formatDate()}` function, you'd have to homegrow it yourself. You can find a kickoff example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472699/jstl-fmt-library-throws-500-error-requires-sessions-enabled/3472823#3472823).

---

**Update** as turns out per comments, the `${status.value}` is actually a `String` in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. If fixing it to be a fullworthy `Date` is not an option, then you would need to parse it into a `Date` first with help of `<fmt:parseDate>` before feeding it to `<fmt:formatDate>`.

```
<fmt:parseDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${status.value}" var="parsedStatusDate" />
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${parsedStatusDate}" var="formattedStatusDate" />
<input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${formattedStatusDate}" />
```

Comment: Hi BalusC, This didnt work value="<fmt:formatDate pattern='MM/mm/YYYY' value="${status.value}"/>"

Comment: What happens instead? Do you have declared the taglib in top of JSP? Did you fix `YYYY` to be `yyyy`? Note that I updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: fmt taglib was missing. Fixed it and tried running. This is what I got: Status Code 500 
Exception Type class javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException 
Message Attempt to convert String "2002-04-15" to type "java.util.Date", but there is no PropertyEditor for that type 
Exception javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: Attempt to convert String "2002-04-15" to type "java.util.Date", but there is no PropertyEditor for that type

Comment: Then `${status.value}` returns `String` instead of `Date`. Fix it accordingly so that it returns `Date`. Or if that is not an option due to some stupid business restrictions (why would you ever hold date as string though?), then use `<fmt:parseDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${status.value}" var="${parsedStatusDate}">` to convert `String` to `Date` first, which you in turn feed to `<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${parsedStatusDate}" />`.

Comment: BalusC, second option didnt work either. On that its complaining: JSPG0046E: Unable to locate tagfile for tag formateDate <br/> Even though I have declared <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

Comment: ok. got it. Thanks for the guidance. Gonna try conversion and post back :)

Comment: As to the `formateDate`, I made the mistake to copypaste your typo :) It has to be `formatDate`. Do you have Spanish roots or something?

Comment: Lol... no I dont have spanish roots :)

Comment: Bingo. You are the best. It worked :) Is it possible for you to modify your solution from value="${parsedStatusDate}" to value="parsedStatusDate" because its throwing exception

Comment: Sorry, comments can't be edited anymore after 5 minutes. I'll however include it in the answer.

Comment: ohk. Thanks for all the support BalusC