# can i write some code in my model(form)..?? i want to change date format, while populating date values on my jsp page

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, model

I am writing simple CRUD(Create, Remove ,Update ,Delete) application using Spring MVC and hibernate.

In Create i can add membership start date in MM/dd/yyyy format.

In Update i want the same data to be display(populate) in my jsp.
My problem is at the time of update my date input field is showing date in yyyy-MM-dd format.
I find out the solution for this 
At the time of getting values(in my model's getter method) ,i have written one small code as below:

```
public Date getDateOfIncorporation() {
        Date date=null;
        try {
            Date abc = this.dateOfIncorporation;
            if (abc != null) {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                String formattedDate = df.format(abc);
                date= df.parse(formattedDate);              
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

but **i am confused about my approach** .
is this the right way or am i doing any mistake by writing **this code in form(model)** .???

since i want to maintain good coding standard , i need your suggestions on the same.
is this acceptable , if any senior reviews my code ...??

Comment: if you are saving date in db in (MM/dd/yyyy) format. then is it not picking up same value in update mode ???

Comment: no it's still giving me in some MON 17 ........ fromat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually it should be done in the view (i.e. your jsp) have a look at the JSTL format taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
```

and especially its pattern attribute (e.g. `pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"`)

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${yourDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

Comment: but how to do this ...??  my jsp code is    <td class="col"><label>Date of Incorporation</label> 
          <form:input path="dateOfIncorporation" type="text" class="textbox calender" name="dateincorp" onclick="displayDatePicker('dateincorp');" id="dateincorp"/> 
          <a href="javascript:;" class="calenderbttn" onclick="displayDatePicker('dateincorp');"></a>
          </td> where to put this fmt tag..??

Comment: see my last edit... the "yourDate" content can also be a getter call to your model, sth. like value="${myModelBean.dateOfIncorporation}"

Comment: thnaks but if i use fmt tag , i can not use class,onclick, name and id attributes, is there any other alternatives!!!

Comment: you can have the fmt tag as your value for the form input... have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231288/jstl-format-tag