# JSTL Date format patterns apply to a text field?

Tags: html, date, jstl

I have gone through all the formats and able to work with them.
All examples shown are for just displaying only.. But If it is a text field then how to change the apply the date pattern..
Eg:

```
<input type="text" value="parsedDate"/>
```

In this case how to format the date ???

all examples are showing only for eg:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" type="both" timeStyle="long" 
dateStyle="long" />
```

I want to apply the date format for text field...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="<fmt:formatDate value='${date}' type='both' timeStyle='long' dateStyle='long' />"/>
```

or

```
<fmt:formatDate var='formattedDate' value='${date}' type='both' timeStyle='long' dateStyle='long' />
<input type="text" value="${formattedDate}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the following link..  [Solution To Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231288/jstl-format-tag)
And it is only working for html elements.But not for the taglibs provided by the frameworks like struts , stripes etc...

Comment: You shouldn't answer to yourself with what is NOT an answer. You're shooting yourself in the foot by doing that, since everybody knows the question is already answered. Edit your question instead. Using the "edit" link at the bottom of the question.