# SQL is returning only the year, not the day nor the month

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm working on a small personal project as a Java student and i've been asked to create a simple webpage that displays a Mysql database. In mySql, i declared my dates in type DATE.
See screanShot below.

[image]

The java code below shows how i retrieve the datas from my DB.

```
private Destination resultSetRowToCursist(ResultSet resultSet)
            throws SQLException {
        return new Destination (resultSet.getInt("CountryID"),
                resultSet.getString("Destination"),
                resultSet.getDate("DepartureDate"),
                resultSet.getDate("ReturnDate"), 
                resultSet.getInt("Price"),
                resultSet.getInt("AvailableSeats"));
    }
```

Below is the screanshot of the output on my webpage.
DepartureDate and ReturnDate format on my webpage should be reflecting the same format as in the DB

[image]

This is my JSP code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css">

    <title>Travels</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table border=1>

            <tr>

                <th>CountryId</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>DepartureDate</th>

                <th>ReturnDate</th>

                <th>Price</th>
                <th>AvailableSeats</th>

    </tr>

            <c:forEach var="destinationArrayListItem" items="${DestinationArrayList}">

                <tr>

                    <td>${destinationArrayListItem.countryID}</td>
                    <td>${destinationArrayListItem.destination}</td>
                    <td>${destinationArrayListItem.departureDate}</td>
                    <td>${destinationArrayListItem.returnDate}</td>
                    <td>${destinationArrayListItem.price}</td>
                    <td>${destinationArrayListItem.availableSeats}</td>


                </tr>

            </c:forEach>

        </table>



        <br />

        <c:url var="index" value="/IndexServlet" />

        <a class="HPbutton" href="${index}">Home Page</a>


    </body>
    </html>
```

My Destination class with COnstructor and getters

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

public class Destination implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int countryID;

    private String destination;

    private  Date departureDate;
    private  Date returnDate;
    private  int price;
    private  int availableSeats;


    public Destination () {
          this.countryID=0;;

          this.destination="geen";

          this.departureDate= null;
          this.returnDate= null;
          this.price=0;
          this.availableSeats=0;


    }

    public Destination(int countryID, String destination, Date departureDate,
            Date returnDate, int price, int availableSeats) {
        this.countryID = countryID;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.departureDate = departureDate;
        this.returnDate = returnDate;
        this.price = price;
        this.availableSeats = availableSeats;


    }

    public int getCountryID() {
        return countryID;
    }

    public void setCountryID(int countryID) {
        this.countryID = countryID;
    }

    public Date getDepartureDate() {
        return departureDate;
    }

    public void setDepartureDate(Date departureDate) {
        this.departureDate = departureDate;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public Date getReturnDate() {
        return returnDate;
    }

    public void setReturnDate(Date returnDate) {
        this.returnDate = returnDate;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getAvailableSeats() {
        return availableSeats;
    }

    public void setAvailableSeats(int availableSeats) {
        this.availableSeats = availableSeats;
    }


}
```

Comment: how is the web page rendering the object?

Comment: Can you please show the `Bestemming` constructor declaration? And how are you showing the Date later?

Comment: Actually Bestemming is Destination in dutch. I just made a correction. please review the code again

Comment: @Rahoul Still: show the constructor code and the getters for the dates

Comment: please show the constructor. Is returndate in Destination a date object?

Comment: Its there. i just posted it

Comment: You have to be aware the Date Object internally has only a number. It is impossible to express only a year with such an object. However, when formatting the date into a String you're free to select what data you want. So I'd recomment you to re-think where your problem is located. A first step might be debug the consturctor and to see what comes there, and then to follow the data through the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using javax.sql.Date or java.util.Date. Remebering that EL tags use the toString() method, it may be worth formatting the date as shown in the following thread:

[Convert java.util.Date to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

Another way to do this is to use JSTL tags in the following manner:

```
<td><fmt:formatDate value="${destinationArrayListItem.departureDate}" pattern="MM/yyyy" /></td>
<td><fmt:formatDate value="${destinationArrayListItem.returnDate}" pattern="MM/yyyy" /></td>
```

To do this, you will have to add the JSTL library to your JavaEE application as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Note, this is different from the JSTL core.

Comment: I'm using import java.sql.Date;

Comment: That's fine and it's good that you're using sql.Date. You may want to look at the JSTL library with JSPs. It can make date formatting and other things a lot more easier and it's fairly easy to learn and implement.

Comment: Ok, i'll try and i'll come back to provide a feedback

Comment: Sorry, yes, you've got JSTL core in your code. I didn't realise it before. That means that you should be able to insert the code in my answer. If not, then please let me know.

Comment: I'm getting an yellow warning in my JSP when i use your fmt:format:  error says:  number format value does not support runtime expressions?

Comment: You must import the following JSTL library (additional to the JSTL core): <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %> As for yellow warnings, don't worry about them too much as they are for HTML checking. JSPs are different

Comment: Thank you for your help but this <fmt:format...> doesnt work. Returning HTTP status 500 :  According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: That is very strange because the taglib import in my answer should work. Please note that the taglib import in my previous comment has a semi-colon that should not be there.

Comment: Now the yellow warning is gone after removing the semicolon (great) but when i launch my app, tomcat gives me a : HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/JSP/showDestination.jsp at line 45 . Fyi, Line 45 is the line with the fmt tags.

Comment: You may want to see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231288/jstl-format-tag

Comment: It's working now and I could not tell you how I've fixed it. I just created a new DB in mysql and BOUM !!. Thank you friend. NB: I did not use the fmt jstl tag